# How can I convert row data to column in PHP

Tags: php, html, pivot, fetch

I have an academic table that contains data.

eg:

| level | percentage |
| --- | --- |
| Degree | 50 |
| Diploma | 70 |
| Post Diploma | 67 |

This is my code, but not working:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Degree</th>
    <th>Diploma</th>
       
    $stmtc = $conn->prepare("SELECT 
    MAX(CASE WHEN level = 'Degree' THEN percentage END) AS $degree,
    MAX(CASE WHEN level = 'Diploma' THEN percentage END) AS $diploma 
    FROM tbl_academic_qualification WHERE member_no = '$emp_id'");
    $stmtc->execute();
        $resultc = $stmtc->fetchAll();
        foreach($resultc as $rowc){
            $degree = $rowc['percentage'];
            $diploma = $rowc['percentage'];
                                                                
    ?>
    
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo "$degree"; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo "$diploma"; ?></td>
        </tr>

</table>
```

I want to display like this:

| Degree | Diploma | Post Diploma |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 50 | 70 | 67 |

Comment: It looks like you have not closed your `for` loop.

Comment: Your injected variables should use parameter binding, not string interpolation. The latter approach can cause security problems.